# Error message in C# 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a project coded in C# 2008 express. It runs without problem in C#2008.
I ran it in C#2010 express, after conversion, unfortunately, I get the following error message :

> "Specified value of type
>   'System.Windows.Media.Media3D.Point3DCollection'
>   must have IsFrozen set to false to
>   modify."

The place I get the error:

```
private MeshGeometry3D GetShipAxisConeX_Mesh3D()
        {
            Point3D[] AxisCone_pts = GetAxisConeVertices();
            for (int say11 = 0; say11 <= 306; say11++)
            {
                ShipAxisConeMeshX.Positions.Add(AxisCone_pts[say11]);    // HERE
            }

.
.
.
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Regards,

Can

Comment: Thank you very much for reply. The problem is that : How to unfreeze ?

Comment: Sorry, Could you say me why there is no any problem in C#2008.

Comment: Check what version of .NET you are running in each environment, I was reading off of the 3.0 docs, previous versions might be more forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

The object is frozen: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.freezable%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Which means its immutable unless you unfreeze it.

To unfreeze the object you have to Clone it, see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750509%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#frozenfreezables (scroll down to unfreezing a freezable).

Comment: @user689908 - (your comment should have been in reply to @chotcki rather than on your original post) - You need to understand under what conditions it gets frozen.  It may not be available to you as unfrozen at any time for what you're trying to do as the result of some breaking change in the framework you're using?